# Java:How to restrict to adding sub classes in the collection?

Tags: java

Can anyone please tell me the solution for the below question:
I have a super class named A,and few sub classes named B,C.The both sub classes B and C extends A.
I want to add the super class object in the collection(like arraylist) not sub class objects.
I mean the collection should allow only super class object not sub class object.

Comment: This might be a sign that you're using `extends` in a way you probably shouldn't. What actually are the superclass and subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with static typing.

If you really need to do this, you need to write a collection class that uses

```
  element.getClass().equals(someClass)
```

to test that the (candidate) element satisfies your restriction.

Comment: @sharonbn `(new Subclass()) instanceof Superclass` will be true.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it with `java.util` implemented colletions. You need to write your own collection that will check element's class and choose whether to add it or not. And you can still implement `List<E>` for example.

But it more looks like a design issue of your way of using class inheritance, like maybe those classes B,C shouldn't extend A.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the Lower Bounded Wildcards of Generic to limit it.

For example:

```
List<E super A> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, the `aList` can only accept the super class of `A` (Of course, including Class `A`).

See the details:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html

Comment: You can't use "super" or "extends" generics when instantiating a type. It's used for method signatures, mostly (as in the example in your link).

Comment: Furthermore, lower bound specification on a variable is useless... consider  the following code: `List<? super Object> aList = new ArrayList<Object>(); aList.add(2);`. It works, and by your reasoning it shouldn't.

Comment: Really?Thank you for your noticement. I made a mistake.